# [JQuery/Ajax]Lower the delay on click

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, ajaxform

I have a little issue with my Ajax function : I cannot lower the delay once clicked on the button register.

I first click on the button from the form on submit, then it wait like 3seconds, then it launches : "signing in" - little delay - showing message.

How to make it like once clicked on that button, it launches directly the ajax function : "signing in" - little delay (for the loading image) - show message ?

**My Ajax**

```
$('document').ready(function(){

$(document).on('submit', '#formRegister', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('input+small').text('');
    $('input').parent().removeClass('has-error');
    $.ajax({
        method: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: "json"
    })
        .done(function(data){
            $('#btn-signup').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" /> &nbsp; signing in...').prop('disabled', true);
            // Loading gif.
            $('input[type=text],input[type=password]').prop('disabled', true);
            // Disable the input text and password

            setTimeout(function(){

                $('#error_register').slideDown('fast', function(){
                    $messageRegister = "The message";
                    $('#error_register').html('<div class="alert alert-info">'+$messageRegister+'</div>');
                    // Show the message from the variable.
                    $("#formRegister").trigger('reset');
                    // Reset the form
                    $('input[type=email],input[type=password]').prop('disabled', false);
                    // Enable the input text, email, password
                    $('#btn-signup').html('Submit').prop('disabled', false);
                }).delay(3000).slideUp('fast');
                // Hide the div that contain the message.
                window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},4500);
                // Reload page after 4.5 seconds.

            },3000);

        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            $.each(data.responseJSON, function (key, value) {
                var input = '#formRegister input[name=' + key + ']';
                $(input + '+small').text(value);
                $(input).parent().addClass('has-error');
                $('#btn-signup').html('Submit').prop('disabled', false);
            });
        });
});
```

})

**Html register form** :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myRegister" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Register</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <!-- json response will be here -->
            <div id="error_register"></div>
            <br>
            <!-- json response will be here -->

            <form id="formRegister" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('register') }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
                        <small class="help-block"></small>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email">
                        <small class="help-block"></small>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                        <small class="help-block"></small>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                        <button id="btn-signup" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                            Register
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The function register**

```
    /**
 * Handle a registration request for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    $user = $this->create($request->all());
    $user->confirmation_code = str_random(30);
    $user->save();

    event(new Registered($user));

    $this->notifyUser($user);

    return response()->json();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the values given on the end of the setTimeout method calls?  Or taking them out completely?  You're going to have some delay due to your ajax call processing, but the setTimeouts are artifically created delays by your logic.

Comment: Yes, once I add some delay, it increase the loading time for the circle image or reduce it.

But it doesn't affect the click button.

Comment: Just for clarity, what are you calling the click button?  Your logic is based around a submit event.

Comment: I am calling the function register, inside the RegistersUsers trait from the RegisterController, originally made with php artisan make:auth, that I modified to make it an ajax json response.

Comment: Aah okay I get you.

I meant my form submit "onsubmit". 
Everything is working.

However once I click on submit through the button on the form, it wait a few seconds before the ajax to be launched.

I was wondering if it was possible to reduce it.

Comment: I don't see anything in your logic that would delay the ajax *from starting*.  I do see a 3000 millsecond setTimeout that would delay the slide down from happening.  And then a subsequent 4500 millisecond setTimeout delay on a window reload.  Edit: There's also a 3000 millisecond delay() between the slide down and slide up.

Comment: Move the spinner logic out of the done function of ajax. Put it instead directly before ajax call.

If you look in developer console in network tab i am sure you will see that your ajax request happens instantly, but then you have some strange timeouts i would remove.

Comment: Yup thank you Larsemil, problem solved !